# PowerPoint VBA macro to skip animation on a slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I've got some PowerPoint slides containing various pieces of custom animation (e.g. piece of text appears, pause, next piece of text appears, user clicks to show image). However, is it possible to add a macro so that the user could click a button and bypass all the animations to jump directly to the end state of the *same* slide? I know how to link a macro to a button, it's just the VBA itself that's the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
Sub JumpToEndOfAnimations()

Call SlideShowWindows(1).View.GotoClick(msoClickStateAfterAllAnimations)

End Sub
```

Comment: Yep, msoClickStateAfterAllAnimations is exactly what I was looking for! Although the strange thing is is that the slide show doesn't update automatically. It does if I add a MsgBox alert to the Sub, but that's not suitable for our end users. So in the end I found that adding the following triggered a Slide refresh:     ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.Height = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.Height - 1
    ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.Height = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.Height + 1

Answer (score 0):

You can add a duplicate of the slide in its end state with no animations, hide it, then add an action button on your animated slide that links to the hidden, unanimated version of the same slide.

Comment: I did consider this, but the PowerPoint files will ultimately be used by teachers and this duplication could easily confuse some of them.